# Using multiple select box by select2.js

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-select2

I use [select2.js](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) for creating select box, I have two different select box in my page and they have different style. So if I separate the CSS class, it will caused the jquery scripts.

I added some changes, from `.select2-container .select2-choice span {... }` to `.accoutbox .select2-container .select2-choice span {... }` , it works. But some block of div, is not in `accountbox` div, so I cannt do it, such as `.select2-drop.select2-drop-above {....}`.

Any idea is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select2 has a `dropdownCssClass` property where you can specify a custom class to be added to the `select2-drop` class, e.g.

```
$("#your-selector").select2({
    dropdownCssClass: 'some-custom-drop-class'
});
```

Then you could just do something like this instead:

```
.some-custom-drop-class.select2-drop-above
```

More: [Select2 documentation](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#documentation)

Comment: I did it with `.select2-drop.some-custom-drop-class`, anyway thanks for pointing it out.